# Object type null value check

Tags: c#, asp.net, null

I am using  bellow code to get date value from ListviewDataItem control

```
object HyperWalletPayoutDate = 
    DataBinder.Eval(dataItem.DataItem, "HyperWalletPayoutDate");
```

some time HyperWalletPayoutDate value come null. How can i check this null value ?

I have tried this way but not working

```
if (HyperWalletPayoutDate.Any() == null || HyperWalletPayoutDate == "" 
    || HyperWalletPayoutDate ==null)
```

Please give me suggestion to solve this problem. Thanks in advance ..

Comment: why not just  `HyperWalletPayoutDate ==null` ??

Comment: HyperWalletPayoutDate ==null this check not working. I am getting value HyperWalletPayoutDate =={}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you are seeing (the value is `{}` rather than `null`) is a result of [Boxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/yz2be5wk.aspx). Assuming you are expecting a `string`  value you should use the correct check for that particular type i.e.

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)HyperWalletPayoutDate)) {
   ...
}
```

This will internally unbox the value and determine whether it has a value.

Comment: the best overloaded method match for (String.IsNullOrEmpty(string) has some invalid arguments

Comment: Thanks James. Its working now  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(HyperWalletPayout.ToString()))

Comment: @Liton it's probably safer to cast directly than calling `ToString`, if `DataBinder` does happen to return `null` (there's no guarentee that implementation won't change) then at least this code won't blow up.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that the first condition

```
if (HyperWalletPayoutDate.Any() == null || ...
```

already requires an instance. You have to perform the `null` check on `HyperWalletPayoutDate` first:

```
if (HyperWalletPayoutDate == null || HyperWalletPayoutDate == "" || HyperWalletPayoutDate.Any() == null)
```

when `HyperWalletPayoutDate` is `null`, the other conditions are not evaluated, so no exception is thrown anymore.

Comment: I have checked this way but not working ..this HyperWalletPayoutDate value come only second bracket {}

Comment: @Liton if the `if` condition does not evaluate to `true`, `HyperWalletPayoutDate` is not `null`, and there is something else causing trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I think it works like this:

```
    if(HyperWallenteretPayoutDate.Any(d => d)){ 
        //it does not equal null 
    }
```

Comment: showing Error :“'object' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'property' accepting a first argument of type 'Any' could be found”